Не работает схема операционного усилителя в Multisim
У меня есть задание:
Входной сигнал - электрическое сопротивление от 8,2кОм до 4,1кОм
Выходной сигнал - постоянный ток от 0 до 5В
Питание от +-12В
Я посчитал и получил вот такую схему 
Но когда начал тестить в Multisim получилось, что не работает схема. Что не так в мультисиме или может быть в моей схеме? 
Вот ссылка на источник https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Qv78/SfK5PdkkR
7 и 11 слайды

Давненько я не брал в руки шашек© Вы точно уверены, что источник сигнала должен находиться в цепи обратной связи первого каскада, а не представлять собой делитель на одном из входов? Можно ссылку на литературу - откуда взялся такой подход?

Ну так вот же, вам всё обозначено: ваш вариант - слайд №9. На один вход - опорное напряжение , на другой - делитель, одно плечо которого - резистор-источник сигнала. С какого перепуга он у вас в обратную связь-то попал?


Вот такая должна быть схема включения для измерения сопротивления, в вашем случае - термистор надо заменить вашим переменником

А можете пояснить выбор диф усилителя? Я пытался через инвертирующий усилитель и сумматор. И почему не работал multisim, если расчеты и эмулятор на сайте показывали, что все работает

начнем с того, что я обучение по этому предмету закончил в 1996 году :) и больше тяготел к цифровой схемотехнике, но, всё таки к теме - тут классический случай, типовое включение:  дифференциальный усилитель - электронный усилитель с двумя входами, выходной сигнал которого равен разности входных напряжений, умноженной на константу. У вас в условии прямо так и написано в первых 2-х пунктах. Ваш выбор я даже как-то обосновать не могу, уж не обессудьте. Если будут требовать обоснования по элементной базе, а скорее всего будут - пункт 2.9 - обратите внимание на ТКС резисторов делителя и их допуски

и да - там у вас на картинке откуда-то взялся диапазон -10-5в, который, скорее всего и сбил с толку

Тут не особо-то и думать надо - как измерить сопротивление: измерить падение напряжения на нём и сравнить с образцом (заданным делителем R1/R3), скорректировать коэффициент обратной связью - R2
